# DNS zone overlap

Tags: linux, dns

We have two zone `www.example.com` and `example.com`, our website hosted on www.example.com so it has `@  IN  A  x.x.x.x` record in `www.example.com` and every this working fine. But today we host website on cloudfront and they said point www.example.com to CNAME cloud hosted server. Now if I add `@  IN CNAME  cloudfront.blah.com` give me error and if I'm trying to put that entry in example.com it's not working because we have `www.example.com` zone there. What would be best way to handle it.

Comment: Do you have records besides the origin in the `www.example.com` zone?

Comment: Your question is not clear, give the true names involved, because I doubt that `www.example.com` is a zone

Comment: @patrick it's confidential i can't reveal the original name of company. hope you understand policy.

Comment: @thrig yes we have many record in `www.example.com` zone besides `@` origin

Comment: Sorry, can't help you then. The DNS is public, obfuscation is useless. Beside, you are surely paying CloudFront for a service, did you ask them for help?

Comment: Bottom line CNAME never work on `@` origin (It is called breaking the law of DNS) address so found other work around which is `Proxypass` method and it works! i think i am all set.